# How can i use animate right for sidebar menu in phone view?

Tags: java, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a portal called https://schooldukan.com/esythink/  ,when i click on toggle bar menu on phone view animate-left is working fine means it comes slowly as i want but when i click on cross button to close it animation doesnot works, means it disappear very quickly. i want to use animate-right, so that when i click it wil close slowly, how can i do that please help..[image: phone view image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method instead of "display block".

```js
$('.navbar-toggle').click(function(){
  $('#text1').toggleClass('move')
});
```

```css
#text1{
      position: fixed;
  left:-100%;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

#text1.move{
  left:0;
}
```